# Embarcadero windows libraries and packages

Tags: opengl, c++builder

This is my first time with Embarcadero RAD Studio (C++, not Delphi) and, despite of many searches on its site and the rest of Internet, I'm still confused with some concepts.

My goal, by now, is to set a OpenGL Core Profile and go on with OGL stuff (which I'm acquainted with). With other IDE/Compiler I'd add the `opengl32` library, use `wglCreateContextAttribsARB` and `glew`.

Digging into Embarcadero files I find `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\lib\win32\release\psdk\opengl32.lib`, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\lib\win32c\release\psdk\opengl32.lib` (note the 'c' after win32, what's that?) and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\lib\win64\release\psdk\opengl32.a`

So I suppose I could just "Project->Add to Project..." the library, instead of "import" from Windows system as it seems was needed many years ago. But I'm confused because RAD may add the required libs on its own, at least for controls, right?

But I've meet with ".pas" files, which seems to load anything needed. Actually, the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\source\rtl\win\Winapi.OpenGLext.pas` seems enough, so I could avoid `glew`. My confusion is that I don't know if a ".pas" file can be used (and how) for VCL C++, not Firemonkey, not Delphi.

I have not be able to find `wglCreateContextAttribsARB`, nor a replacement for setting a Core Profile context.

Summarizing:

1. Do I need to add system libs? How?
2. How to use ".pas" files?
3. Which is the difference between `win32` and `win32c` dirs?
4. How to set a OGL Core Profile context? I mean, should I go with the route of retrieving a function pointer to
   `wglCreateContextAttribsARB` or RAD provides another way?
5. Does RAD provide for C++ a replacement of glew?

Comment: "*note the 'c' after win32, what's that?*" - C++Builder has [multiple C++ compilers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/C%2B%2B_Compilers). `win32c` is probably for the `bcc32c` compiler, which is one of the [Clang-based compilers for Windows 32-bit](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Win32_Clang-enhanced_Compilers). "*I don't know if a ".pas" file can be used (and how) for VCL C++*" - C++Builder projects can use Delphi `.pas` files, but you don't need to use `Winapi.OpenGLext.pas` itself, just use `#include <Winapi.OpenGLext.hpp>` in your C++ code instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau THX. I missed that `Winapi.OpenGLext.hpp.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1.Do I need to add system libs? How?

Normally yes. unless you are using a component that has taken care of adding the library. In Win32 you have to use `#pragma link "opengl32.lib"` and in win64 you have to add `#pragma link "opengl32.a"` to your cpp code.

> 2.How to use ".pas" files?

You do not need to add the files in the source directory to your project. Embarcadero is nice enough to include the source code for most of its components with the product. This is so you could understand how it works and if you need to change some behavior you can create a new class derived from the class that you want and override the function in question. In general C++ builder allows adding Pascal units to C++ project and it will take care of creating the header file automatically. But in your case it is not necessary.

> 3.Which is the difference between win32 and win32c dirs?

C++ builder comes with 2 32 bit compilers for Windows. One is clang based and supports C++14 and the libraries that have been compiled with it are in `win32` directory. The other one is the classic compiler and the libraries that have been compiled with it are in `win32c` directory. Unless you have checked the "Use Classic Compiler" in project settings, you don't have to worry about it.

> 4.How to set a OGL Core Profile context? I mean, should I go with the route of retrieving a function pointer to wglCreateContextAttribsARB
>   or RAD provides another way?

I'm not aware of any components that RAD studio may provide. You should search https://torry.net/ or http://www.delphipages.com/ or many more places that exists out there for a component that helps you whith what you need.

> 5.Does RAD provide for C++ a replacement of glew?

What is "glew"?

Comment: "*C++ builder comes with 2 32 bit compilers for Windows*" - actually, it has **3**: `BCC32`, `BCC32C`, and `BCC32X`.  "*One is clang based and supports C++14*" - **2** are Clang-based, and as of 10.3 Rio, they now support C++17 (the Clang-based compilers for other platforms do not, yet). Prior to Rio, they supported C++11, not C++14. Embarcadero has never released a C++14 compiler, they jumped from C++11 straight to C++17.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found [this blog with video](https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/b/blog/posts/mixing-delphi-and-c) where there's some explanation about `.pas` files and adding them to the project.

Comment: For OGL > 1.1 a header and a lib is not enough. The function pointers for each OGL function must be retrieved from the lib. This is what `glew` does. And it seems that `Winapi.OpenGLext.pas` does it too at `InitOpenGLext` procedure. So i can consider that if using RAD then `glew` is not needed. I will test it.

Comment: The OGL Core Profile and `wglCreateContextAttribsARB` usage don't exist in RAD (or they are deeply hidden). So I use "manual" setup. See [wiki explanation](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context_(WGL)) and [wiki sample](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tutorial:_OpenGL_3.1_The_First_Triangle_(C%2B%2B/Win))

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @Ripi2 I found an example of how to use the OPENGL for Delphi [here](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/26401). It should be easy to translate that into C++ Builder.

Comment: @Sam THX. Yes, I'm aware of that example. But it's for old OpenGL 1.1 and I use new, modern, OpenGL >= 3.2